# Do python list comprehensions get converted to pure C?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've been told multiple times that Python list comprehensions are better than nested `for`, `if` simply because they are converted to pure C and compiled. However, I cannot find any documentation to support this; is this true?

For example; the following below code actually does result in 1/3 performance gain (on my machine):

```
import time

start = time.time()
a = []
for i in range(0, 100000000):
  a.append(i)

end = time.time()

print("Time it took: " + str((end - start)))

start = time.time()
b = [i for i in range(0, 100000000)]
end = time.time()

print("Time it took: " + str((end - start)))
```

CPython results:

```
Time it took: 12.077988863
Time it took: 8.65817594528
```

PyPy results:

```
Time it took: 4.9356508255
Time it took: 0.686870098114
```

Comment: Maybe this will help?: http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2008/06/list-comprehension-implementation.html

Comment: plus one for showing some code. By the way, addressing that now.

Comment: CPython never "compiles" anything to pure C.  but some paths can be faster, if they minimize how much work needs to be done in Python-land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implementation specific, but in CPython, it's not compiled to C, but it is compiled to what is called "bytecode".

We can inspect it with the `dis` module which is used to disassemble bytecode.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     return [i//2 for i in range(20)]
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (20)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             25 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE 
             26 LIST_APPEND              2
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   32 RETURN_VALUE
```

In other implementations, it could be compiled to C. I am much less familiar with those other implementations, so I'll withhold commentary on them.

Regarding your statement:

> list comprehensions are better than nested for, if ...

In some cases, it makes more sense to use the for list and conditions. The best approach is to use what it most readable to you, and then profile your code if you need to improve performance. Sometimes you don't actually need the list or generator created by the list comprehension or generator expression, and when that's the case, using the for loop with the if condition is generally more performant.

#### speculation:

However, in the example you give, you specifically are intending to create a list. Appending to the list in a loop is the canonical way to do it, but as you know from checking your runtimes, the list comprehension is faster. The reason it is faster is because the designers of Python know a list comprehension will be populating a list, so there are opportunities to optimize it. In a for loop, optimizing it would be more difficult, because you have to be able to process much more complex statements there.

I imagine your huge improvement in PyPy is due to an optimization that optimizes on the i for i part, and perhaps simply calls `list` on your iterator.

Comment: Worth noting: bytecode is specific to CPython; some interpreters (like PyPy) do actually compile everything directly to machine code using JIT.

Comment: @nneonneo To nitpick, PyPy does use bytecode (and it's virtually identical to CPython's bytecode) and *later* compiles *some* parts of the program to machine code.